# Creating a shell script to compress files using Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, shell-script, compression

I've got a minor project wherein I'm to create a few shell scripts in Windows and run them through Cygwin for Linux files. At least that's how it was described to me. 
Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? ([man tar](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do it is using gzip to compress files.

If you need to package multiple files up into one big one, try looking into tar, then gzip them after you do that.

It sounds like an assignment so that should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm supposed to use Cygwin. At least that's what I was advised to download today.

Comment: CygWin includes tar and gzip if you choose it to, you tell it which parts to download ;)

Comment: That sounds great! Appreciate it.

Comment: If it wasn't explained to you well enough, CygWin is 'Linix/Unix Commands For Windows' in a pre-built package with addons. Glad to help!

Comment: Yeah, this was sort of a "I want you to write some shell scripts to compress and move files. Download Cygwin as part of the exercise." type of assignment.

Comment: It is an amazing compilation.

Comment: tar has the capability to compress by itself... use the _holy_ man! IT's the help. man tar and you can read a lot about the command and discover other, slightly better' compression method. E.g. bzip2.

Comment: It does but if you have worked with Linux distros for any amount of time you will find out that the generally accepted method is precisely what I prescribed. Tar + gzip consolidated to .tgz -- Bzip2 is another one yes. Same thing. This was forward thinking help not unilateral.

Comment: @Hastur has a very good point and you will find that Unix/Linux offers many ways to reach the same goals.